# Scraping Google App All Reviews using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scrape all reviews from google play store for a particular app. I have prepared following script:

```
# App Reviews Scraper
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=en&showAllReviews=true"

# make request
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 5

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

# Get everything inside <html> tag including javscript
html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

reviewer = []
date = []

# review text
for span in soup.find_all("span", class_="X43Kjb"):
    reviewer.append(span.text)

# review date
for span in soup.find_all("span", class_="p2TkOb"):
    date.append(span.text)

print(len(reviewer))
print(len(date))
```

However, it always showing 203 only. There are 35,474,218 number of reviews. So, how can I download all the reviews?

Comment: If you inspect the completly behavior you will see that you also have to look if a *show more* link appears from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,1)


try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Show More']"))).click()
except:
    continue
```

Just add this to check for the show more element in your infinite scroll.

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: '@Arundeep' thanks a lot, its working fine. Now facing another problem: sometime error shows in browser, and it gets stuck (could not scroll down, but wait for infinite time). If I close the browser manually, it does not show any review. Does there have any option to close the browser automatically if any error occurred, and reviews till that point will be shown?

Comment: driver.close() for closing and you could put the grabbing elements inside the scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

#### An easier method to scrape app data from play store

```
!pip install google_play_scraper 

from google_play_scraper import app

#US Market Google play store reviews
from google_play_scraper import Sort, reviews_all
 us_reviews = reviews_all(
'add the app id here-using the string mentioned after id value in your code', # use the id from the play 
 store hyperlink that you have used above
 sleep_milliseconds=0, # defaults to 0
 lang='en', # defaults to 'en, can change to other lang as well'
 country='us', # defaults to 'us'
 sort=Sort.NEWEST, # defaults to Sort.MOST_RELEVANT
```

)

#### Convert into a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(us_reviews ),columns=['review'])
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('review').tolist()))
```